# Conditionals calculations across rows R

Tags: r, dplyr

First, I'm brand new to R and am making the switch from SAS. I have a dataset that is 1000 rows by 24 columns, where the columns are different treatments. I want to count the number of times an observation meets a criteria across rows of my dataset listed below.

```
            Gene        A       B        C         D
1         AARS_3       NA      NA 4.168365        NA
2 AASDHPPT_21936       NA      NA       NA -3.221287
3     AATF_26432       NA      NA       NA        NA
4       ABCC2_22 4.501518 3.17992       NA        NA
5    ABCC2_26620       NA      NA       NA        NA
```

I was trying to create column vectors that counted

- 1) Number of NAs
- 2) Number of columns <0
- 3) Number of columns >0

I would then use cbind to add these to my large dataset

I solved the first one with :

```
NA.Count <- (apply(b01,MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x) length(x[is.na(x)])))
```

I tried to modify this to count evaluate the !is.na and then count the number of times the value was less than zero with this:

```
lt0 <- (apply(b01,MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x) ifelse(x[!is.na(x)],count(x[x<0]))))
```

which didn't work at all.

I tried a dozen ways to get dplyr mutate to work with this and did not succeed.

What I want are the last two columns below; and if you had a cleaner version of the NA.Count I did, that would also be greatly appreciated.

> ```
>              Gene        A       B       C          D   NA.Count   lt0   gt0
>  1         AARS_3       NA      NA 4.168365        NA     3         0      1
>  2 AASDHPPT_21936       NA      NA       NA -3.221287     3         1      0
>  3     AATF_26432       NA      NA       NA        NA     4         0      0
>  4       ABCC2_22 4.501518 3.17992       NA        NA     2         0      2
>  5    ABCC2_26620       NA      NA       NA        NA     4         0      0
> ```

Comment: R is happen to be a vectorized language. You can do stuff like `rowSums(is.na(b01[-1]))` or `rowSums(b01[-1] > 0, na.rm = TRUE)`
or `rowSums(b01[-1] < 0, na.rm = TRUE)` or `rowSums(sapply(b01[-1], is.na))` or ```Reduce(`+`, lapply(b01[-1], is.na))``` or many other options

Comment: With dplyr, this will work (if you ok with some warnings regarding the `Gene` column `b01 %>% mutate(NA.count = rowSums(is.na(.)), lt0 = rowSums(. > 0, na.rm = TRUE), gt = rowSums(. < 0, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: data.table would be useful to avoid the warnings by using the .SDcols option: `library(data.table)`
`DT = data.table(DF)`
`DT[,gt0 := rowSums(.SD > 0,na.rm = TRUE),.SDcols = c("A","B","C","D")]`

Comment: @AndresT you can do `.SDcols = -1`....

Comment: Thank you so much David! I knew I should have asked sooner. I've spent literally hours trying to solve this.

Comment: @akaDrHouse The best way to learn is to first try it yourself. If you always ask, you will never learn.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I tried to create another column based on gt0 and lt0 as follows:  b01$test %>% mutate(test=(if((gt0>0) & (lt0>0)) 1 else 0))  and got::

Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Is there a good reference with examples for this kind of stuff; I know it is simple stuff if you know it, but the syntax learning curve for 45 ways to do every task in R is um..noticeable to me.  Thanks much.

Comment: Maybe `b01 %>% mutate(test = as.integer((gt0>0) & (lt0>0)))` ? don't use `b01$test` when using `dplyr`. `mutate` will create `test` for you.

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg.  I was able to create test but only with a vector of TRUE/FALSE which I was then able to sum as R treats it as 0/1.  When I tried to add in if/then logic it failed.  I finally resorted to:   b01<-within(b01,test[(b01$gt0 > 0)&(b01$lt0 > 0)] <- 1)

Comment: You don't need the `if` `else` logic. Just try my code `b01 %>% mutate(test = as.integer((gt0>0) & (lt0>0)))`

Comment: Sorry, your code worked and gave me a vector of TRUE/FALSE. I was trying to get the mutate to work with IF/ELSE logic for future reference when I needed to explicitly define other conditions, or more than dichotomous outcome.

Comment: This should return an integer vector, not logical....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it taking advantage of the fact that TRUE equals 1 in R.

```
# test data frame
lil_df <- data.frame(Gene = c("AAR3", "ABCDE"),
                 A = c(NA, 3),
                 B = c(2, NA),
                 C = c(-1, -2),
                 D = c(NA, NA))

# is.na
NA.count <- rowSums(is.na(lil_df[,-1]))

# less than zero
lt0 <- rowSums(lil_df[,-1]<0, na.rm = TRUE)

# more that zero
mt0 <- rowSums(lil_df[,-1]>0, na.rm = TRUE)

# cbind to data frame
larger_df <- cbind(lil_df, NA.count, lt0, mt0 )

larger_df
  Gene  A  B  C  D NA.count lt0 mt0
1  AAR3 NA  2 -1 NA        2   1   1
2 ABCDE  3 NA -2 NA        2   1   1
```

Comment: Thanks M_Fidino for taking the time to lay that out.  David Arenburg had provided the same information in a comment and I very much appreciate the response.